# In raster set NA to zero where other rasters has value in that cell

Tags: r, arcgis, raster

I have 11 big raster files containing about 314578920 cells. Some of these cells contain NA. I want to replace NA to zero if other rasters has value in that particular cell. But cells that contain NA in all rasters should be the same. For example, see the image below:

[image]

I have created five rasters (top row) to illustrate my question (but actually I have 11 rasters). The output rasters should be like the bottom row rasters.

Replacing all NA's to zero (i.e., using `r[is.na(r[])] <- 0`) makes the raster so big that the memory cannot handle. Or, omiting NA's does not serve my purpose. Any idea on how to solve this will be highly appreciated.
Sample code:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5) # create empty raster
r[] <- rnorm(length(r))     # assign random values to each cell
r[1:5] <- NA                # assign first row with NA
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with working with rasters to confidently create a sample "raster object" to test code on. Can you offer MWE code that generates a few small rasters? For instance, it doesn't matter that yours have 314M cells, the code may work as well with a 10x10 raster as it will with 17Kx17K.

Comment: @r2evans Is this code serve your question: `library(raster) # load library; r <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5) # create empty raster; r <- rnorm(length(r)) # assign random values to each cell; r[1:5] <- NA # assign first row with NA`
head(r) # see few rows of the created raster`

Comment: It's a good start. I added it to your question, in the future just add it there yourself (comments are generally horrible at showing code beyond simple single-line commands).

Comment: That's one raster, you said you were comparing multiples with some-same, some-different `NA` locations. Your sample data should really be self-sufficient, so if you need a list of rasters or separate objects, you need to create them.

Comment: Do you know how frequently this conversion will occur? For instance, your statement that the raster gets *"so big that the memory cannot handle"* will be a factor no matter what technique is generated to replace "some" `NA`s with 0. Perhaps this is a case where you need (1) a bigger computer; (2) a change to your algorithm that can smartly deal with these `NA`s without filling up the sparse matrix; or (3) something else.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to calculate the range of rasters cell by cell (using `calc` function of raster package). That's why I need to convert NA's to zero for cells that contain values in other rasters. If converting all NA's to zero then each raster file gets more than 4gb in size that the computer memory cannot allocate. I need some codes that conditionally converts NA to zero for cells that contain values in other rasters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick hack that replaces `NA` values that are not `NA` through all provided rasters. Any cell that is `NA` in all provided rasters will remain `NA`. (I'm assuming, btw, that all rasters are the same size ...)

I'll make some even-simpler data. I'm choosing to store them in a list, since that makes this solution significantly easier to read (I think), but also much easier to extend to as many rasters as you need.

```
set.seed(2)
rs <- lapply(1:2, function(ign) {
  r <- raster(nrow=3, ncol=3)
  r[] <- sample(length(r))
  r
})
```

I'll create two types of `NA` in this data: one that is in both (and should be ignored), and one that is in one only (and should be replaced with 0):

```
rs[[1]][1:2] <- NA
rs[[2]][2] <- NA
lapply(rs, head)
# [[1]]
#    1  2 3
# 1 NA NA 5
# 2  9  7 4
# 3  1  8 3
# [[2]]
#   1  2 3
# 1 5 NA 2
# 2 8  1 7
# 3 3  4 6
```

Rasters internally (as you likely know) are just `numeric` vectors, so I'll map which indices are `NA` for each one.

```
nas <- lapply(rs, function(r) which(is.na(r[])))
nas
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
```

Knowing that, we can find the indices that are common to all. There might be something easier than this, but it works (and is readable):

```
na_in_all <- Reduce(intersect, nas)
na_in_all
# [1] 2
```

Now we just remove all indices that are present in all:

```
nas <- lapply(nas, setdiff, na_in_all)
nas
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# [[2]]
# integer(0)
```

Now we just re-iterate over the rasters and this list of indices-to-be-replaced:

```
rs <- mapply(function(r,i) {
  if (length(i)) r[i] <- 0
  r
}, rs, nas)
head(rs[[1]])
#   1  2 3
# 1 0 NA 5
# 2 9  7 4
# 3 1  8 3
head(rs[[2]])
#   1  2 3
# 1 5 NA 2
# 2 8  1 7
# 3 3  4 6
```

This does not necessarily address your issue of sparse-matrices growing too big, but this is almost certainly better than the global replace-all-`NA` in your question.

Comment: Thank you. But the last function gives me error: `Error in (function (r, i)  : unused argument (simplify = dots[[3]][[1]])`. Is anything missing. I have now pasted the function in below comment and will deleted after you correct me.

Comment: Oops, I was supposed to test that before posting ... remove it, and things work fine. (It was a post-test addition to the code. Unnecessary.)

Comment: Yes, I have up-voted the answer (i.e., accepted). But who has down-voted to my original question? Thank you a lot mate.

Comment: For whomever downvoted the answer, can you please advise why? Just curious to know what could have been better (or less wrong).

Comment: can you please edit your answer so that I can upvote again (just put any word in code comment). My pc got hang yesterday. I have accepted the answer and want to upvote again. Regards.

Comment: Your upvote is still there, I believe, it shows "0" because somebody downvoted it. \*shrug\*. Thanks for the thought!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do that with "terra"

Example data

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(nrow=5, ncol=5, vals=1:25)
set.seed(20181801)
s <- rast(lapply(1:5, function(i) {r[sample(25, 15)] <- NA; r}))
```

Three solutions (`x`, `y`, and `z`)

```
a <- allNA(s) 
x <- ifel(is.na(s), ifel(a, NA, 0), s)

# or 
y <- mask(subst(s, NA, 0), a, maskvalue=TRUE)

# or
b <- is.na(s) & (!allNA(s))
z <- ifel(b, 0, s)
```

---

With the older raster package
Example data:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5, vals=1:25)
set.seed(20181801)
s <- stack(lapply(1:5, function(i) {r[sample(25, 15)] <- NA; r}))
```

Count `NA` values across layers

```
i <- sum(is.na(s))
```

Reclassify such that all cell values become zero, except when all layers had a `NA` value

```
nl <- nlayers(s)
j <- reclassify(i, rbind(c(0, nl-1, 0), c(nl, nl ,NA)), right=NA)
```

Use `cover` to replace `NA` values with zero in the cells where there is at least one layer with a value

```
z <- cover(s, j)
```

Alternative approach with `calc`:

Write a function that does what you want for a vector or matrix:

```
f <- function(x) {
    i <- sum(is.na(x))
    if (i > 0 & i < 5) {
        x[is.na(x)] <- 0
    }
    x
}

zz <- calc(s, f)
```

An important reason for using these functions over more direct R idiom is that they are all memory-safe.

By the way, you mention that `r[is.na(r[])] <- 0` did not work because of memory limitations. By doing `is.na(r[])` you create a vector of all values, and thus ask for that problem to happend. You could instead try `r[is.na(r)] <- 0`.